# set nofoldenable not working in my vim - why?

Tags: vim, markdown

Every time I open one of my markdown (`.md` extension) files in my MacVim, they automatically fold lots of lines, which is a pathetically frustrating feature in almost all cases. And even after I added `set nofoldenable` in my `~/.vimrc`, it doesn't disable the feature at all. Writing in `~/.gvimrc` doesn't work, either.

So is it feasible to disable it? And what am I missing?

I also wonder why the depressing folding feature only functions in my markdown files. As far as I know, all the other extension I use don't conform to the functionality.

I use OS-X default Vim 7.3 and Mavericks 10.9.1.

Comment: in your markdown file, do you have modeline?

Comment: What does "set ft?" say the file type is?  Perhaps a file type plugin is loaded when you open the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with

`au FileType markdown setlocal nofoldenable`

Comment: Thanks. For some reasons, your answer didn't work, but tried to replace `markdown` with `mkd`, and now everything is working well. For your information, `set ft` returns `filetype=mkd`.

Comment: I guess it depends on specific plugin that is used to implement markdown filetype.

Comment: I just checked:`Vebose set ft -> filetype=markdown Last set from ~\vim\vim74\filetype.vim`. So this is set by vim itself.