# vim set nofoldenable not working

Tags: vim

I have two machines that are kept almost at identical configuration. Both having vim 8. The issue is when I open a tex file, on one machine the folds are correctly disable as is dictated by set nofoldenable in .vimrc on the other machine with identical .vimrc file the folding is not disabled upon opening a file.

I even tried au FileType markdown setlocal nofoldenable as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547681/set-nofoldenable-not-working-in-my-vim-why) but folds are still there.

Where can the difference be? And more importantly why is vim ignoring this particular command in .vimrc (other commands get executed just fine).

Comment: maybe you have a different `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` on each machine?

Comment: Use `:verbose set foldenable` to discover where it is set.